# npm 404 Not found, well known package

Tags: npm, npm-install

Trying to install 7zip-bin package using npm, bring this error:

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: 7zip-bin@5.0.3

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/user/.npm/_logs/2020-02-11T22_06_51_357Z-debug.log
```

In the log file I see this output:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '-g',
1 verbose cli   '7zip-bin@5.0.3' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v8.15.0
4 verbose npm-session 57413e14b663097a
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readGlobalPackageData
7 http fetch GET 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/7zip-bin 522ms
8 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for 7zip-bin@5.0.3 404 Not Found: 7zip-bin@5.0.3
9 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 0ms
10 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 745ms
11 verbose stack Error: 404 Not Found: 7zip-bin@5.0.3
11 verbose stack     at fetch.then.res (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/fetchers/registry/fetch.js:42:19)
11 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
11 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
11 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
11 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
11 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromises (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:693:18)
11 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueue (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:133:16)
11 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueues (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
11 verbose stack     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
11 verbose stack     at runCallback (timers.js:810:20)
11 verbose stack     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:768:5)
11 verbose stack     at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:745:5)
12 verbose cwd /Users/user/Projects/fotomaster.com/mosaicpresentation
13 verbose Darwin 18.7.0
14 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "7zip-bin"
15 verbose node v8.15.0
16 verbose npm  v6.4.1
17 error code E404
18 error 404 Not Found: 7zip-bin@5.0.3
19 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I know I had this package installed already and didn't do anything to uninstall it.
What do I miss?

Comment: I tried with older versions as well, but with the same outcome.
Apparently is something traced here: https://github.com/develar/7zip-bin/issues/9

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/7902) they seems to find the problem on the npm registry side. Still not working for me though...

Comment: For me, the issue was being on an outdated version on npm (6.4.1)
Updating to 6.13.4 fixed it for me

Comment: Updating `npm` worked for me as well! Thank you!

Comment: @Harry Please, post it as answer. It helped me too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[reference](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/7902#issuecomment-584890654) to github yarn [issue#7902](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/7902)

add `registry=https://yarn.npmjs.org` to file **~/.npmrc**.
This fixed the problem for me.

Comment: The problem was an incident on the npm side: https://status.npmjs.org/incidents/lvgmcrfvrvsh

Answer (score 0):

Was getting the same error. I installed the module using yarn add instead. Can you check if your package has yarn.lock file?

Answer (score 0):

same problem, adding explicit dev dependency fixes it, but it looks like a bug

Comment: Adding it to the dev dep in the .package.json didn't solve the problem for me. What have you done exactly?

Answer (score 0):

The other solutions didn't work for me

For me, the issue was being on an outdated version on npm (**6.4.1**) 
Updating to **6.13.4** fixed it